# Determine number of function given two sets and properties

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let A={1,2,3,4,5,6,7} and B={v,w,x,y,z}. Determine the number of functions $f:A \rightarrow B$ where (i) f(A)={v, x}; (ii) |f(A)|=2

For (i) the answer key gives 2!S(7, 2) and (ii) $\binom{5}{2}[2!S(7,2)]$

I don't understand where these answers come from. So the sterling number of the second kind shows how many non empty subsets of size 2 can be made from the domain A but why is 2! used and where does the $\binom{5}{2}$ in (ii) come from?

Comment: The $2!$ comes from which of the two parts goes to $v$ and which goes to $x$.  The ${5\choose 2}$ comes from which two elements are the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, the factor of $2!$ arises from the following.  If you look at the subset of $A$ that maps to $v$, and similarly for $x$, you obtain a partition of $A$ into two parts, but those parts are *unordered*.  Exchanging the roles of $v$ and $x$ gives a distinct function.  How many ways are there to rearrange the two element set ${v, x}$?
$$2!$$

As for your second question, out of the five element set $B$, you must choose $2$ elements to be the range, and then the previous calculation applies.  How many choices are there?
$$
\binom{5}{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, $S(7,2)$ is the number of ways to partition $A$ into two non-empty sets. We need to know this, since, in order to have $f(A)=\{v,x\},$ we need $f$ to be a function such that $A$ is the disjoint union of the sets $$\{n\in A:f(n)=v\}$$ and $$\{n\in A:f(n)=x\}.$$ These two sets cannot have any elements in common, since we want $f$ to be a function. Both of these sets must be non-empty, since we want $\{v,x\}\subseteq f(A).$ Every element of $A$ must lie in one of the two sets, since we want $f(A)\subseteq\{v,x\}.$ Once we've partitioned $A$ into two non-empty subsets, though, we must still pick which set's elements get sent to $v$ and which set's elements get sent to $x.$ There are $2!$ ways to do this. Hence, there are $2!S(7,2)$ functions of the first type.

For the second one, the idea is much the same, but the range of $f$ can be *any* $2$-element subset of $B$. How many such subsets are there?

Comment: what is wrong with this logic: How many functions do we have from $\{1,\ldots,7\}$ to $\{v,x\}$.  There are $2^7$ functions.  However, even these functions may not have it be the case that their image is surjective.  So really we are asking how many surjections there are.  If we consider how many functions there are which are not surjective, the answer is 2, since ignoring one variable leads to a constant function.  Therefore there are 2^7-2.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that logic at all! You should find that in fact, $2^7-2=2!S(7,2).$

Comment: Okay thanks.  That's helpful - I guess that's some sort of identity?

Comment: Sure is. If you know the identity $$S(n,k)=\frac1{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}{j}j^n,$$ then in particular, $$\begin{align}2!S(7,2) &= 2!\cdot\frac1{2!}\sum_{j=0}^2(-1)^{2-j}\binom{2}{j}j^7\\ &=\binom{2}{0}0^7 -\binom{2}{1}1^7+\binom{2}{2}2^7\\ &= 2^7-2.\end{align}$$

Comment: To be quite honest, in circumstances like this, your approach is plenty simple, and there's really no need to resort to Sterling numbers in your answer.